# Pygame Surface layers: Transparent sprite layer issues

Tags: python, pygame

I am drawing a small colored square, using `surface.fill(color, rect)`, on a sprite surface, which is then be displayed on top of the other surfaces in the following order:

1. Background surface
2. Maze surface
3. Sprite surface

Currently I am having a problem where my sprites smear across the screen because I'm not wiping the screen each time. **How can I eliminate this smearing effect, while keeping the sprite layer from covering the other layers?**

**Layers code - Initialized, but not updated each frame.**

```
game_surface = pygame.Surface((self.canvas.get_size()))
game_surface = game_surface.convert()
game_surface.fill((0,0,255))
maze_surface = pygame.Surface((self.canvas.get_size()))
maze_surface = maze_surface.convert_alpha()
maze_surface.fill((0,0,255,0))
play_surface = pygame.Surface((self.canvas.get_size()))
play_surface = play_surface.convert_alpha()
play_surface.fill((0,0,0,0))
```

Presently only the `play_surface` actually actually uses transparency, but eventually both the `play_surface` and the `maze_surface` will need to be transparent.

**Sprites layer update - Called every time the sprite is moved.**

```
def update(self, canvas):

    # move sprite if keys pressed (not shown)

    self.surface.fill((0,0,0,0)) # Newest screen fill attempt. Causes smearing effect
    self.surface.fill(self.color, self.rect) # draw green square
    canvas.blit(self.surface, (0,0))
```

**Smear effect: Red = `maze_layer`, Green = smeared sprite**
[image: Red = maze_layer, Green = sprite]
**Alternate sprite fill - Altered version of the above**

```
def update(self, canvas):

    # move sprite if keys pressed (not shown)

    self.surface.fill((0,0,0)) # Original screen fill. Covers up lower layers
    self.surface.fill(self.color, self.rect) # draw green square
    canvas.blit(self.surface, (0,0))
```

**Non-transparency - Black = filled color (I want to do this without covering up the other layers)**
[image: Non-transparent :(]

**How can I eliminate this smearing effect (pic 1), while keeping the sprite layer from covering up the other layers (pic 2)?** Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redraw the background covered by your sprites, update their positions, and then redraw the sprites in their new position.

You may be interested in exploring the `pygame.sprite` module which has built-in support for this functionality.  You can create subclasses of `pygame.sprite.Sprite` that:

1. Override the `update(self)` method (optional)
2. Have `self.image` and `self.rect` attributes that are used to draw them to screen
3. Are added to `pygame.sprite.Group` instances

Pygame's sprite group classes (such as `Group`, `GroupSingle`, `LayeredUpdates`, etc.) include methods like `pygame.sprite.Group.clear(surface_dest, background)` (see the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.clear)) to facilitate the task of re-drawing background images on your sprites before moving and re-drawing them elsewhere.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a way to do this without redrawing the background each frame, because the background isn't going to change and redrawing it would be redundant.

Comment: Well the Pygame display surface has had the sprites drawn over a part of the background, so it's mandatory that at some point, the background is drawn again there.  This can, however, be optimized by only redrawing the region under each sprite, as opposed to the entire screen.  The `pygame.sprite.Group.clear` method I mentioned will only redraw the areas under the `rect` attributes of each `pygame.Sprite` in the group which may help.

Comment: I tried to create a `Sprite` group and object, but I'm getting the error `'Player' object has no attribute 'image'`. I don't want to use an image to represent the sprite, which is why I use the `fill` method. Do you know how I could draw sprites without assigning an `image` attribute?

Comment: I don't think the `pygame.sprite` module has anything to support that kind of custom drawing.  You can probably just maintain a `rect` attribute, and use `self.image = None` for your sprites.  Then you can use the other functionality, and handle drawing using your own system.

Comment: As far as I've tried, using the `sprite.Group.clear` causes my drawing functions to either break, or work improperly. The screen clears, but the sprite doesn't draw (just a red screen).